# Vote up or 'Like' Post/Reply

Tags: forum

How would i go about introducing some sort of 'like post' feature in EE's discussion forum.

Something similar to Solspace's 'Rating' module would be great, is it possible to use this with discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I wonder if you could use the comment feature to make a "Like" system.

Assuming you aren't using comments for the things you wish to add the "Like" feature to. Imagine if the "Like" button submitted a hidden comment form with minimal/common detail in it. You can then show the count of the number of comments as "Likes".

Comment: Is that possible to do with discussion forum post?

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread and didn't realise it was within the discussion forum. To be honest, I have no idea as I've only used the Forum module once, a long time ago. In fact for functionality similar to a forum I have previously hijacked EE's normal entries and comments.

Comment: Yeh i did think about that at one point, only after I had done the work on the forum module though! Doh. Thanks for response.